# Intellisense C++ file with alternative extension

Tags: visual-studio

Hi fellow programmers,

I have a C++ file with the extension .inc that is getting included from another C++ header. My problem is that the intellisense is inactive for this file, all the text just showing up black. I am using visual studio 2015. I have looked everywhere inside visual studio with no luck.

Is there any way to activate intellisense for this file?

Thanks in advance,
Jakob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell VS that those .inc files are in fact C++.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension and add your .inc:

[image]

You need to restart Studio, at least for version 2013.